# How to build for Pocket PC 2002 with Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, pocketpc

Is there any way to build for Pocket PC 2002 (3.0) with Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 3):

Pocket PC 2003SE is the oldest version I've seen support for (and I have done a couple myself).  I *think* Visual Studio 2003 was the last time Pocket PC 2002 could be targeted.

[Details on VS2008 support](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowsmobile/archive/2007/07/30/visual-studio-beta-2-professional-available-for-download.aspx)